Where to put public key in arch wiki?
It's now about two hours I'm browsing arch wiki to put my public key and publish my AUR but I cannot find which part of user panel is for that. Can anyone help me with this?

Are you talking about your SSH key for pushing packages to AUR? If so, you go to https://aur.archlinux.org/account/<username>/edit and add it to the "SSH Public Key" field.

@muru: yes. put it as answer so I can accept it.

According to the Arch Wiki:

For write access to the AUR, you need to have an SSH key pair. The content of the public key needs to be copied to your profile in My Account [...].

The "My Account" page is the one in https://aur.archlinux.org:

And it typically has an URL of the form https://aur.archlinux.org/account/<username>/edit.
